# Exclude folder from indexing in PhpStorm / WebStorm

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, node-modules

Using PhpStorm 2017.3 to dev a node project; there are certain directories that I wish to exclude from indexing and auto-complete suggestions. I've seen elsewhere directions that I followed but still no dice. In the image below for example, the directory `rxjs/add` is one of them.

[image]

On the left side of the image, you can see that in the Project tree view, the directory is not excluded; I get auto-complete suggestions from its contents. However when I go to `Settings > Directories`, the same folder (see the right side of the image) is already listed as excluded. Not sure what to do. This is a `node_modules/` directory for the `rxjs 5.5` package.

**The problem I'm actually trying to solve:** this library has multiple functions with the same name from different files. So when I use a function and the IDE tries to automatically add the ES6 import statement, it shows me multiple options and every time I have to carefully read the file paths to select the correct import. Because the correct import always comes from the same two directories, I'd like to tell the IDE to stop looking into the others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebStorm/PhpStorm auto-exclude `node_modules` folder from the project, but direct project dependencies listed in `package.json` are added to **JavaScript libraries** for completion/navigation and thus indexed.
To exclude certain module, you can comment it out in the `package.json`; or, in  **File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries**, disable the `<project_name>/node_modules` library and create your own library (by pressing **Add...**) with only desired modules/files included

Comment: Thanks lena. I don't want to disable indexing for the whole library. Just certain folders within the library. For instance, in my screenshot above I want `rxjs/add` and `rxjs/operator` to not be indexed, but I want `rxjs/operators` and `rxjs/observable` to be indexed.

Comment: see my answer - make sure to only add those files that you'd like to be indexed

Answer (score 15):

Open the IDE *Settings > Directories -> Select the folders you want to exclude > click "Excluded" Button*

[image]